# Will vs Would? Can both of them be used for future

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

1. I doubt she will do anything.
2. I doubt she would do anything.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Please also mention if there is any grammatical error in the following sentence:
"The lady listened carefully to my complaint but I doubt she will do anything about it."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your sentences are grammatically correct and both have a future meaning: we understand that she hasn't done anything yet and that she is unlikely to do anything *in the future*.

Your other sentence,

> The lady listened carefully to my complaint but I doubt she will do anything about it.

is very possible. I guess your concern is about using past and present in the same sentence. It is alright to do that, since the two actions do not both take place in the past. Think of:

> I know *(now)* that the lady listened carefully *(in the past)* to my complaint, but I doubt *(now)* she will do anything about it *(in the future)*.

Answer (score 3):

"Will" is more of a definite future mood, while "would" is a conditional mood, which usually depends upon some other "if" condition.

For example:

> "...I doubt that she *would* do anything about it (*if* she had the chance)".

On the other hand...

> "... I doubt that she *will* do anything about it"

suggests that she is perfectly able to do something, but she just won't.

Comment: +1 for a clear and succinct answer.